# How to follow MVC if you have lot of static data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, model-view-controller

I am developing an iPhone application in it I am having around 15 arrays and 15 more array which has value in it corresponding to the value in array e.g. NSArray *XYZ = {a,b,c,d} and array NSArray *ABC = {w,x,y,z} such that value 'a' corresponds to 'x' .Can comebody tell me what is the best way to follow MVC in this scenario like I have to make function (returning array) for each array in another class or should I make class for every array.

Comment: So far, you've just described a data structure, not an _object_. An object has _behavior_. Before determining where in the MVC triumvirate your object fits, it is necessary that you describe its behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write all your business logic as classes with those arrays in a **MODEL** file, access those classes from the **CONTROLLER** file. And then once you have all your data, access from the **CONTROLLER** the **VIEW** file to output. Inside the **MODEL** write functions for those arrays so that you can reuse them, if they vary they may need own functions. This is a helpful link: http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/ and those videos give you a taste of the logic behind MVC: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HFQk8WGK1-Q&feature=bf_prev&list=UU9-GXsmQQ-N4h8ZsKI8CSkw